# how to make correct array for leaf realtime in json

Tags: php, arrays, json, leaflet

I am trying us to leaflet.js realtime. I have it working when I encode the coordinates like below. I have read the instructions and it does not specify how it wants the data but found this in a sample. How do I encode it to print it out as it should and is it possible to include more than one set of coordinates?

Any help would be great, thanks.

my php

```
$lat = "52.45238209999999";
$lng = "-1.743507099999988";

$str = "{".chr(34)."geometry".chr(34).": {".chr(34)."type".chr(34).": ".chr(34)."Point".chr(34).", ".chr(34)."coordinates".chr(34).": [".$lng.", ".$lat."]}, ".chr(34)."type".chr(34).": ".chr(34)."Feature".chr(34).", ".chr(34)."properties".chr(34).": {}}";

echo $str;
```

and this is how it should look at the end according to the sample.

```
{"geometry": {"type": "Point", 
              "coordinates": [-104.53702657476524, 1.4311558884747997]
             }, 
              "type": "Feature", 
              "properties": {}
            }
```

Comment: Have a read about [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which will take an array and build the JSON for you.

Comment: yes, I can build one just I dont understand the format its in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the output your after, it's a case of building up a multidimensional array with the right structure so that you can then [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) it.

```
$lat = "52.45238209999999";
$lng = "-1.743507099999988";

$data = ["geometry" => ["type" => "Point",
    "coordinates" => [(float)$lng, (float)$lat]],
    "type" => "Feature",
    "properties" => (object)[]
];

echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

gives...

```
{
    "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -1.743507099999988, 52.45238209999999
        ]
    },
    "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {}
}
```

Comment: thankyou and what about more than one set of geometries?

Comment: also i notice your from the west midlands, so am I from Coventry. I have another leaflet bit of code if your interested in looking at something else after this???

Comment: When you say *more than one set of geometries*, what do you need to do as this is something I haven't used before and can't test it.

Comment: nope still doesnt work! This is how it should be: $str = "{".chr(34)."geometry".chr(34).": {".chr(34)."type".chr(34).": ".chr(34)."Point".chr(34).", ".chr(34)."coordinates".chr(34).": [".$lng.", ".$lat."]}, ".chr(34)."type".chr(34).": ".chr(34)."Feature".chr(34).", ".chr(34)."properties".chr(34).": {}}";

echo $str;

Comment: The lat and lng were the other way round.

Comment: it works, but does'nt give the same result!! It zooms into map a lot more for no reason?

Comment: Only just managed to find http://geojsonlint.com/ which allows you to test the JSON and see what it gives, may have to play with this at some point :)